# Issues with unresolved externals from TensorFlow 2.4 C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, bazel

I built the TensorFlow v2.4 C++ API on Windows and now I am trying to run my application, however the linker complains for unresolved externals.
I am trying to build a library with some custom OPs which I was successfully able to compile under Linux, but on Windows I get this:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl tensorflow::Status::Status(enum tensorflow::error::Code,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::vector<struct tensorflow::StackFrame,class std::allocator<struct tensorflow::StackFrame> > &&)" (??0Status@tensorflow@@QEAA@W4Code@error@1@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@$$QEAV?$vector@UStackFrame@tensorflow@@V?$allocator@UStackFrame@tensorflow@@@std@@@5@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl tensorflow::Status::Status(enum tensorflow::error::Code,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >)" (??0Status@tensorflow@@QEAA@W4Code@error@1@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) TF_Project  main_cc.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class tensorflow::Status __cdecl tensorflow::GetNodeAttr(class tensorflow::AttrSlice const &,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,int *)" (?GetNodeAttr@tensorflow@@YA?AVStatus@1@AEBVAttrSlice@1@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PEAH@Z) referenced in function "public: class tensorflow::Status __cdecl tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext::GetAttr<int>(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,int *)const " (??$GetAttr@H@InferenceContext@shape_inference@tensorflow@@QEBA?AVStatus@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PEAH@Z)  TF_Project  main_cc.obj 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl tensorflow::kernel_factory::OpKernelRegistrar::InitInternal(class tensorflow::KernelDef const *,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::unique_ptr<class tensorflow::kernel_factory::OpKernelFactory,struct std::default_delete<class tensorflow::kernel_factory::OpKernelFactory> >)" (?InitInternal@OpKernelRegistrar@kernel_factory@tensorflow@@AEAAXPEBVKernelDef@3@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@V?$unique_ptr@VOpKernelFactory@kernel_factory@tensorflow@@U?$default_delete@VOpKernelFactory@kernel_factory@tensorflow@@@std@@@6@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'register_kernel_4''(void)" (??__Eregister_kernel_4@@YAXXZ) TF_Project  main_cc.obj 1
```

I tried all sorts of things, I compiled tensorflow.dll, tensorflow_cc.dll and tensorflow_framework.dll
I tried to link against all 3 in all sorts of combinations, but the missing symbols are not found.
Am I missing some library that I should link against?

I did a simple test to verify that the libraries I built are valid and they seem so.

Calling  `tf_monolithic_build();` and `tf_compiler_version();`
does not produce unresolved externals and returns expected results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1:**
Tried to do some digging on the first error.

The Status class is contained within 2 files : `status.h` and `status.cc` that live in `tensorflow\core\platform`

The problematic missing constructor is indeed defined in `status.cc`, so that should mean that `status.cc.o` is not part of `tensorflow_cc.dll`?

Why can this be? In `tensorflow\core\platform\BUILD` I can see these is some code for compiling the files to a library called `status`

```
cc_library(
    name = "status",
    srcs = ["status.cc"],
    hdrs = ["status.h"],
    deps = [
        ":logging",
        ":macros",
        ":mutex",
        ":stacktrace",
        ":str_util",
        ":strcat",
        ":stringpiece",
        ":stringprintf",
        ":types",
        "//tensorflow/core/protobuf:error_codes_proto_impl_cc",
        "@com_google_absl//absl/base",
    ],
)
```

Unfortunately my Bazel-fu is very limited and I have no idea how to verify that this library is indeed compiled during the 6 hour long process and is indeed wrapped inside the final DLL file.

Comment: The DLLs you built should have also built their corresponding LIBs.  You need to link against them.

Comment: Of course. I thought that was kindof obvious so I didn't write it down, my bad. I did link with the LIB files and put the DLL files in PATH so that the application can find them... however didn't get to the DLL actually loading, as linking fails before I get the that chance.

Comment: MinGW (gcc) can link with DLLs (dynamic libs) but MSVC can't; so just wanted to check for clarity.

Comment: Interesting :) Didn't know it could do that. I wonder how it knows the symbols' name and declaration then.